HIkari pool exhaustion when scaling down pods
I have a Spring app running in a K8s cluster. Each pod is configured with 3 connections in the Hikari Pool, and they work perfectly with this configuration most of the time using 1 or 2 active connections and occasionally using all 3 connections (the max pool size). However, everything changes when a pod scales down. The remaining pods begin to suffer from Hikari pool exhaustion, resulting in many timeouts when trying to obtain connections, and each pod ends up with between 6 and 8 pending connections. This scenario lasts for 5 to 12 minutes, after which everything stabilizes again.
PS: My scale down is configured to turn down just one pod by time.
Do you know a workaround to handle this problem?
Things that I considered but discarded:

I don't think increasing the Hikari pool size is the solution here, as my application runs properly with the current settings. The problem only occurs during the scaling down interval.
I've checked the CPU and memory usage during these scenarios, and they are not out of control; they are below the thresholds.
Thanks in advance.


Once the number of active connections reaches the maximumPoolSize, the pool becomes exhausted and it is not able to fulfill the application’s need for connections any more. To configure Hikari Connection Pool you can use the application.properties file

spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000(30 sec) spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=500000(50 sec) spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=1200000(2 mins)

as you need
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout by using this property we can change the behavior of connection pool.
This property controls the maximum number of milliseconds that you will wait for a connection from the pool. If this time is exceeded without a connection becoming available, a SQLException will be thrown. Lowest acceptable connection timeout is 250 ms. Default: 30000 (30 seconds). The connectionTimeout applied to getConnection() is decoupled from the creation of new connections and will block.
idleTimeout helps with reducing the pool size after a higher demand load.
maxLifetime Ensure connections are recycled periodically to avoid primitive connections, both(idleTimeout,maxLifetime) will close connections, and the pool will eventually return back to connections.
Note: Pgpool-II will handle connection pooling automatically. You can adjust the pool size and other parameters in the pgpool.conf file. Also refer to this similar github issue.
Edit1: Try Increasing the database connection pool across the pods and also Pod Disruption Budget(PDB) to prevent too many pods getting terminated at a time. This makes sure there is a sufficient number of pods running to handle the traffic and database connections.

Sorry but I didn't get how these properties can help my pool to handle this case. Increasing this values won't solve the issue, It'll make able to wait more for the connections.

@Lucas Guimaraes I have updated my answer in the EDIT-1 Section.
It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further
